# Get List returned in Class from Code Behind no working as expected

Tags: c#, list

I have a C# Class that I created and it's working fine. The class (at this point) just queries SQL and returns the result. I have one method that works great. It returns a single record so no problem there. However, I have more complicated query that returns *n* number of record so I put them in a list. I have played around with many different combinations in order to get the list of items but always run into the same thing:

One scenario will return the entire list but I cannot loop through it because the entire list just becomes a giant string. (This occurs when I user the commented out return (`return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, imagePaths);`)

Another scenario is where I try and run a `foreach` loop on the list to spit the items out one by one. When I do this, it's almost like it's only spitting out one charecter (the current iteration of the foreach/for loop.

So my question is, how do I get into the list that is returned by my class and have it structured properly?

**Class**

```
    public static string getImagePaths(string connectionString, string album)
    {
        int numberOfImages = 0;
        List<String> imagePaths = new List<String>();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;

        sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT ImagePath FROM myDB.myTable WHERE Album = '" + album + "'";
        sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCon.Open();
        reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                numberOfImages += 1;
                imagePaths.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
            //return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, imagePaths);
            return imagePaths.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "An error has ocurred";
        }

    }
```

**Code Behind**

```
    private string getImagePath(int imageId)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["theImageDataBase"].ConnectionString;
        var theAlbum = "searchTerm";
        string images = Fetcher.getImagePaths(connectionString, theAlbum);
        Response.Write(images);
        return "";
    }
```

I have verified that it's got the correct count as far as how many items are actually within the table. There is also another scenario where I just get the return message of `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `

I'm assuming this is the correct way to do it as it appears to be picking up the actual `<List>`

Thanks in advance for any helpful input/direction. Can't find much help on the web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fetcher change this:

```
public static string getImagePaths(string connectionString, string album)
```

To this:

```
public static List<string> getImagePaths(string connectionString, string album)
```

And return this:

```
return imagePaths;
//return imagePaths.ToString();
```

In code-behind do:

```
 private string getImagePath(int imageId)
 {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["theImageDataBase"].ConnectionString;
        var theAlbum = "searchTerm";
        List<string> images = Fetcher.getImagePaths(connectionString, theAlbum);
        foreach (var image in images)
            Response.WriteLine(image);
        return "";
 }
```

This writes out every image on a separate line.  I don't know what you want to do with them, so I can't advise further.

Comment: Thank you, Good Sir. I almost had it...not sure why I didn't try making the actual method itself a List. That makes total since why it would just return a giant string...THANK. YOU.